# How do I copy and paste from a website to a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I copy and paste a long command from a website into a command block?

Comment: That linked question was literally the first result in Google.

Comment: I'm shouting, duh XD....

Answer (score -2):

Just Copy And Paste Like Normal
Ctrl+C On Website Then In Minecraft Ctrl+V

Comment: In the English language, capital letters are typically only used at the start of sentences and proper nouns. Not every word.